# React router how to load css based on global var

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postcss, react-css-modules

I have a node project that creates a static react SPA using:

- react-router
- redux
- postcss
- react-css-modules

It currently loads in a global css file and modular css for each component. On start I fetch a global theme var that will be say 'theme-1' or 'theme-2'. I want to load different css files, same name but different directory path, based on the value of the theme var, Eg:

If theme is 'theme-1' then import '/css/themes/**theme1**/Component.css'.
Else If theme is 'theme-2' then import '/css/themes/**theme2**/Component.css'.

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

*Note that module imports can not be wrapped in an if/else statement as far as I can see.*

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: Yes though only to bundle static dist files.

Answer (score 0):

You could use require:

```
if(...) {
    require('/path/to/theme1.css');
}
else {
    require('/path/to/theme2.css');
}
```